# app work fine in ios 5.1 but crash in ios 6

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, ios6, xcode4.5

My app work fine in ios 5.1 and xcode 4.4.1
Now when I update ro ios 6 and xcode 4.5 it's crash in changing view.
I use storyboard to make my UI.
In first view I get TableViewController and when I select one cell it should go to another view that contains 3 buttons, 1 slider, 1 UITableView and 2 labels. Those thing connect to controller with IBOutlet.
In second view that crash happend after end this method I think

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

and the code stock in this point

```
0x347735aa:  ldr    r4, [r0]
```

What should I do ?
Edit:
Here my stack trace

```
0 objc_msgSend
1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]:
2 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:]:
3 __NSFireDelayedPerform:
4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__:
5 __CFRunLoopDoTimer:
6 __CFRunLoopRun:
7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific:
8 CFRunLoopRunInMode:
9 GSEventRunModal:
10 UIApplicationMain:
11 main at main.m:14:
```

Comment: Load a vaild value into r0? Seriously, isn't xcode 4.5 still under NDA?

Comment: @ott With the public release of iOS6 on Wednesday the NDA is no longer in effect.

Comment: Okay, don't you have a "normal" stack trace then? Not just the last line.

Comment: It would help if you symbolicated the crash report.

Comment: @ott-- I edit and add stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem after trace and read my code over and over.The problem was I used this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

that know which cell did select. But I think ios 6 got problem with that method. So when I changed it to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

everything worked fine.
Still I don't know why that happened.

Answer (score 2):

You have mistake in the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` method syntax.
It should be

`-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` not

`-(void)tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

`tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is only informing the delegate that a row in the table is about to be selected, and you could return `nil` if you do not want a particular row to be selected, or return a different IndexPath if you think your app needs it.

As the method was never intended to trigger a drill down into your detail view controller, I think it is only fair that your old call crashes on iOS 6. You were 'lucky' it worked previously.